# SET on html tag lang attribute asp.net-mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, lang

How do I set (without doing horrible hacks) lang attribute on html tag in MVC

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
</html>
```

In Forms 3.5 this could be done by adding `runat='server'` to html tag and then setting values.
I could not find a 'preferred' way of doing this.
I intend to use it with `css:lang` selector

Comment: It depends on the MVC framework you are using.

Comment: Please do not use w3schools as a reference. [It is a horrible site that contains lots of invalid information.](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET MVC, you can directly edit the tag in the _Layout view or whichever you're using as the master page.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET MVC then please read [the description of the mvc tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc).

Comment: asp.net-mvc4 razor - Quentin

Comment: Answers should be posted as answers, not by editing the question.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Your wish is my command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easiest and most 'correct' way to do this was proposed by @Vimal Stan in the comment.

```
<html 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xml:lang="en"  
lang="@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName">
```

Comment: I found this solution does not work if you are missing the localization resources for the requested page. The thread language will be "resolved" correctly to the supported localization defined in `Startup.cs`, but as you are missing the localization the final localization used will be the default one, not updating the thread `CurrentUICulture`. At the end this is setting the `lang` attribute to a wrong language. 

I'm trying to find a better solution given this situation, but for now I'm out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

C#

```
ElementID.Attributes.Add("attributeyoucareabout","value to give it");
```

Comment: Hi Allen, thanks for your answer. Forgive my ignorance but there are few things that are not completely clear to me. Is this answer for forms? Could you point me to how can one access element in .NET MVC please. Thanks.