# ASP.Net Core incomplete localization - Resolved Language

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-5.0

In a ASP.Net Core web application with **localization files not available to all pages, how can I know the finally resolved language?**

I would like to localize some parts of my ASP.Net Core web application, leaving others in the default language, or a subset of languages. When I provide translations .Net Core just translates the pages, and when I don't .Net Core just serves the default language, which is the behavior I need.

My problem comes when **I need to know the resolved language** to fill in the `HTML5` `lang` attribute in the Razor Pages, so my generated web page is correctly formatted.

[I found this solution:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22513715/8150874)

```
lang="@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName">
```

But does not work in my scenario, because the thread language will be "resolved correctly" to the supported localization defined in `Startup.cs`, but as I am missing the localization file, the final localization used will be the default one, not updating the thread's `CurrentUICulture`.

With `CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` I'm wrongly serving English pages with a `lang` attribute filled with one of the "supported" languages.

**How can I know the resolved language if no localization file is available?**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to route data infromation from query:

```
 var routeData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var r in ViewContext.RouteData.Values)
    {
        routeData.Add(r.Key, r.Value.ToString());
    }

    foreach (var qs in Context.Request.Query)
    {
        routeData.Add(qs.Key, qs.Value);
    }
```

Then use it in your switcher as **asp-all-route-data**:

```
 <a class="dropdown-item small"
     asp-all-route-data="@routeData">
     @culture.Text
 </a>
```

And whenever you need culture info you can request it from route data

You can also add asp-route-culture="@c":

```
 <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Accounts" asp-page="/Index" asp-route-culture="@c" 
                                               >yourlocalizedtext</a>
```

where  c is  `var c = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;`